# Will SiteForce support custom URls or OWN DNS in salesforce?

Tags: force.com, site.com

Does SiteForce support HTTPS custom URLs (not force.com URLs) with our own certificate?

As i want to have my own DNS or custom URLs like ex :-  https://eReq-hpglobal.com.

Rather than using https://eReq-hpglobal.force.com.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done but is not easy since is not something they oficially support. If you are a premier customer, you will need to reach out to the support manager assigned to your account, if you are a basic support customer...good luck!

**UPDATE:** I was not aware that this seems to be possible since the Summer '14  Release. Thanks to Peter Knolle for pointing that out.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000006nxHAAQ

Comment: Have you tried since the Summer '14 release? (I have not) The release notes had [this](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/communities_custom_domain_URL.htm) that seemed to indicate it was now possible and the [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000006nxHAAQ) has been marked delivered.